# Issues opening h5py files

Tags: python, theano, keras, conv-neural-network, h5py

I have been trying to build a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) using Keras and the already pre-trained weights VGG16 following this tutorial:https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras.

When I run the following code:

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from convnetskeras.convnets import preprocess_image_batch, convnet
im = preprocess_image_batch(['examples/dog.jpg'],img_size=(256,256), crop_size=(224,224), color_mode="bgr")

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
## For the VGG16, use this command
model = convnet('vgg_16',weights_path="weights/vgg16_weights.h5", heatmap=False)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='mse')

out = model.predict(im)
```

I get the following error when declaring the model, since it uses the h5py package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Convnets_Setup01.py", line 13, in <module>
model = convnet('vgg_16',weights_path="weights/vgg16_weights.h5",heatmap=False)
File "/home/inigo/convnets_keras/convnetskeras/convnets.py", line 65, in convnet
convnet = convnet_init(weights_path, heatmap=False)
File "/home/inigo/convnets_keras/convnetskeras/convnets.py", line 147, in VGG_16
model.load_weights(weights_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Keras-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2494, in load_weights
f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 207, in __init__
fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 79, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDONLY, fapl=fapl)
File "h5f.pyx", line 71, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1806)
IOError: unable to open file (File accessibilty: Unable to open file)
```

I'm using Keras 1.1.0 with backend Theano 0.9.0.dev3, Python-2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.The version of h5py I installed is 2.2.1

I have tried re-installing the h5py package in case the first one was corrupted. I also tried creating the h5f.c folder manually, but wasn't able to add any additional folders to the h5py directory (usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py)

Does anyone know why this could be happening?